# MySQL joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL. I would like to use bits from each table to come up with ONE table that has 3 columns. Month, Number of clients created and number of client contacted. NOTE: The number of contacted clients is of those that were created in that month. ALSO NOTE: that I am looking for just one point of contact with the client.
The code below does not work

```
select month, count(tb_id), sum(contacted)
from (select ta.id, month(ta.created_at) as month,
             if(ta.client_id is null, 0, 1) as contacted
      from (select c.id, l.created_at, t1.client_id
            from client c left join
                 (select distinct client_id
                  from interactions
                  where created_at >= '2015-01-01'
                 ) t1
                on t1.client_id = c.id
           where c.created_at >= '2015-01-01'
          ) ta
     ) tb
group by month;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you want?

```
select 
    month(c.created_at) as month, 
    count(distinct c.id) as created, 
    sum(month(i.created_month) = month(c.created_at)) as contacted
from client c
left join (
    select distinct month(created_at) created_month, client_id 
    from interactions
) i on c.id = i.client_id 
   and month(c.created_at) = i.created_month
where c.created_at >= '2015-01-01' 
group by month(c.created_at);
```

Comment: Not exactly.So ultimately the table should look something like this

Comment: Not exactly.So ultimately the table should look something like this.   Month  Client_created      Client_contacted
Jan              1456                         35
Feb               205                         10
Of the 1456 clients that were created in January only 35 were later contacted in the same month. O the 205 clients created, only 10 were contacted in the same month. Hope its abit clear now.

Comment: @Chaa22 I made an update, please try it now and see if I understood.

Comment: @Chaa22 And a second update - I realized it was counting interactions more than once.

Comment: Yes it did!!!!! Thank you so much.... I made a few changes and added "(sum(case when.........))" and it ran quicker.